# A beginner Jquery question

Tags: jquery

First of all sorry if its a really stupid question but I'm a beginner.

My problem is I have a form where I can edit user details, it has a radio button, and this form is located in my `edit.php`.

On the `index.php` it shows the users, and I would like to do that in JQuery. If this radio button is checked then add a small image after the users name.

Now I know if the jquery file is included before the form it wont give a result, so I placed it in my footer, I wrote some short code in the firebug console:

```
var something = $("#book_geek:checked").val();
alert(something );
```

It perfectly gives me the value back when I run it on the `edit.php`, but I'm getting *null* on the `index.php`.

My question is, that the jquery file is included in the footer, so it can be accessed globally on the site, then why I cant get the result on the `index.php`?

And really sorry again if its a stupid question but I really couldn't find any correct answer.

Comment: there are no stupid questions, only stupid answers ;)

Comment: check the source of index.php -- see if it has those `<script>` tags that include jQuery

Comment: checked it its nothing wrong with that

Comment: do a view source and post the code here or use pastebin.com

Comment: does the form also appear in index.php?

Comment: no it doesn't, i tried with javascript too but nothing :(

Comment: @Side, if the form is not on the index.php, then the js won't work because it cannot select what is not there.

Answer (score 1):

Put the js in

```
$(document).ready(function() {

});
```

The $(document).ready function says not to run until the DOM has finished being instantiated.

Answer (score 1):

You can put this in your header:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var something = $("#book_geek:checked").val();
    alert(something );
});
```

A few points:

1. The reason I did `jQuery(function($) {...` is that starting with jQuery instead of $ will make it easier for your code to coexist in the future with other toolkits since many other toolkits try to establish their own value for $(). Thus in this sample, you can use $ inside that function call like any sample you're looking at.
2. This attaches a ready listener to the page that will execute when the browser determines the page has completed enough of the initialization process to be ready for the user.
3. You can do this several different times. If there are several things which don't step on each other's toes that you want to do at load time, you can just add several new ready listeners.